# Reverse binary number on LC3 simulator

Tags: assembly, binary, lc3

For example, 10001001 should transform to 10010001. But I even don't know how to start this task. Maybe somebody has already done this and can give me some insights into how to solve it

Comment: This task is equivalent to implementing the bit mirror operation with a bit count of 8 it appears. My code for that is at https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/1c7565e04cc4/source/expr.asm#l1951 but it is 8086 assembly code, not LC3. You do want to find a way to shift out one end of the input and shift the other direction into the output, and then do this 8 times in a loop.

Comment: Which part is causing you problem? Did you make an algorithm? For example, you could test the bits starting from the right using masking and copy the bit into the result register that you keep shifting to the left (by adding itself to itself).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want to check each bit of the input, one bit at a time, and update an answer variable based on the individual bit values.  This is fairly complicated on LC-3 since there is no right shift or division.

So, on LC-3, the best way to handle one bit at a time is go from [MSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Bit_significance_and_indexing) to LSB — using left shift.

If you can add, you can left shift: it is accomplished via doubling the value, which is the same as left shift by 1 bit, and doubling is done by simply adding a value to itself.

Testing the MSB is a matter of checking if the value is negative, which the LC-3 can easily do.

To start, you'll need a variable that holds the tentative answer; start this variable at 0.  You'll also need a loop, and, when the loop is finished, your answer variable will have the reversed bit pattern.

You'll also need a bit position variable.  This variable will hold one single bit in the proper position for the answer.  Start this variable at 1.

The loop will handle 1 bit at a time.

The loop exit condition can be counted, i.e. loop 16 times, then stop.  (Alternatively, you can also use the input value being zero as an exit condition, even if all the bits in the input were set, eventually it will go to zero after 16 iterations.  This would be better since it eliminates the counting variable, and also may early out with still correct answer.)

During the loop you'll update the answer variable, and also set things up for the next iteration of the loop.

In the body of the loop,

- If the MSB in the input is set then add the bit position variable into your answer variable to set the appropriate bit of the answer (otherwise leave as a zero as was initialized)
- Lastly, set things up for the next iteration of the loop:

  - shift the bit position variable left
  - shift the input variable left

---

The bit position variable will go from

```
0000000000000001  // first iteration
0000000000000010  // second iteration
0000000000000100  // third iteration
```

So if the MSB is set in the input then the bit position variable holds the bit in proper position to add into the answer variable.

So, the approach is to pull bits off the MSB side of the input and put them down in the answer using the bit position variable, which starts at the other end, the LSB, thus accomplishing the reversing of the bits.  Both the input variable and the bit position variable change each iteration, using left shift only.

Note that this algorithm updates the input variable (it will got to zero by the end of the loop), so if you need that original input value after, save it as a copy or work from a copy in the loop.